# phonegap developer app behaves differently from the installed apk

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an android app that for now it's simply making a window.location="http://web_app.com" to our web server.

This is all working fine with the apk installed on the device, the problem is that when i'm running the app with phonegap developer, this doesn't work and all i see is my base layout "index.html". Also the orientation plugin is not working either.

Does anyone experienced a similar problem and know a solution for this. I need phonegap developer to be able to debug and quickly teste the app.

I'm using phonegap version 6.3.3 and "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" 1.4.2 and "cordova-plugin-whitelist" "1.2.2"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by phonegap developer app, don't trust that app but trust your apk file.

As your project gets complicated, you wouldn't want to run your app through phonegap developer.